# PHP: Accessing an object property with a variable

Tags: php, json

Let's assume I have an array of object properties I'd like to access:

```
$properties = array('foo', 'bar');
```

I'd like to loop through the object and access these properties dynamically (specifically, I'm trying to dynamically handle missing JSON elements based on an array of expected elements):

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if (empty($item->{$property})) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Each $item in $data should have the properties 'foo' and 'bar'.  I'm handling the cases where 'foo' or 'bar' doesn't exist.

I'm trying to get the loop (in line 3) to access $item->{'foo'} and $item->{'bar'}, but it's not working.

Any idea why?  I'm fairly certain it's a matter of syntax, but obviously I haven't been able to figure this out!

Thanks!

Comment: did you try $data->foo? ($data->$property)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I figured it out...

I think I was working on the wrong portion of the object.

Thanks for the informative answers!

Comment: And why don't you share your solution...?

Comment: @Choy: The solution is in the question.  The method I employed was correct; I was simply looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not use `property_exists($item, $property)`.

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        if ( property_exists($item, $property) ) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're doing involves modifying the original set of items, keep in mind that `foreach` operates on a *copy* of the original array. If you want to modify things in the original array, you'll need to use something like `foreach($arr as $k => $v)` syntax, then modify `$arr[$k]`.